# Suppose $f : [0, ∞) → R $ has continuous first and second derivatives and $f(x) → 0$ as $x → ∞$. If $f'(x) → b $ as $ x → ∞$, show that $b = 0.$

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $f : [0, ∞) → R $ has continuous first and second derivatives and $f(x) → 0$ as $x → ∞$. If  $f'(x) → b $  as  $ x → ∞$, show that $b = 0.$

I tried using L'Hopital Rule here, by constructing 
$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}$.
However, I 'm not sure if L'Hopital Rule can be used here because $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$ can not be used as condition.

I'm stuck in this way, and can't see other ways to solve this problem.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for any $[a,b]$, $\exists \theta(a,b): \theta \in [a,b], f'(\theta)={f(b)-f(a) \over b-a}$. Now take $a_n=f'(\theta(n,n+1))$, it's obvious that $lim_{x \to +\infty}a_n = b$. Show that $lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$.

Note that the proof holds for any $f_0 : f(x) \to f_0$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do here. Could you plz be more specific?

Comment: I offer you some specific sequence $a_n$ so that, on one hand, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = b$ and on the other, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since  $$f'(x)= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},$$ we have, replacing $h$ by $f(x)$ and taking $x\to+\infty$: $$ \lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)=  \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x+f(x))}{f(x)} - 1,$$ and thus $$ \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x+f(x))}{f(x)} =1+b. \tag{$\star$} $$ Now, $b>0$ would imply $f(x)<0$ for large enough $x$, whence $$ \frac{f(x+f(x))}{f(x)} <1, $$ for those large $x$, contradicting $(\star)$. A contradiction is analogously derived from $b<0$.
Hence, $b=0$.

Comment: How do you get $$ \lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)=  \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x+f(x))}{f(x)} - 1,$$?

Comment: @XXWANGL: In the previous display, $h$ is an arbitrary variabile converging to $0$, therefore replacing it by $f(x)$ and taking $x\to+\infty$ works.

Comment: @XXWANGL: Why don't you ask again, if I wasn't able to clarify?

Comment: @XXWANGL: Whatever. In particular, it works because by hypothesis $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to+\infty$.